# show string in asp.net C# messagebox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to show a sting in a asp.net messagebox with C#.

This time I´m using the RegisterClientScriptBlock

```
this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("scriptfails", "<script language='javascript'>alert('This is a test, just klick OK'); </script>");
```

Is it possible to show a string in there or do I have to use another messagebox method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "show a string"? You are already showing a string

Comment: Are you actually asking how to replace `This is a test, just klick OK` with some other text, using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize the method in this way:

```
public void ShowMyMessage(string myMessage) {

    this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("scriptfails", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + myMessage + "'); </script>");
}
```

and call from somewhere:

```
ShowMyMessage("Hi!!");
```

It's just an example it could be better, but can give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var message = "this is my string";
this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("scriptfails", string.Format("<script language='javascript'>alert('{0}'); </script>", message));
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("scriptfails", string.Format("<script language='javascript'>alert('{0}'); </script>", "yourmessage"));
```